# No se envia mi Formulario

Tags: laravel, crud

Empece a trabajar en un proyecto con la versión 5.8
Me tiene loco porque estaba buscando un error pero un formulario En Especifico no se envia. & es cuando se inicia sesión

siempre que intento mandar mi formulario, solo se actualiza la pagina. pero no se envia nada no recibo nada en mi controlador :(

Mi formulario es este

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('entrar')}}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">

<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">
    ENTRAR  
</button>

<button type="reset">Borrar</button>
```

Mi controlador que Http/Controllers
llamada
LoginAccountController

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginAccountController extends Controller
{
    
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        
        return $request;
    }
}
```

Mi Ruta WEb. inclusive borre todas las que tenía solo me quede con estas

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('iniciar-sesion-sistema','LoginAccountController@login')->name('entrar');

Route::get('iniciar',function(){
    return view('sistema.login');
});
```

**DATO CURIOSO, SI EN MI RUTA EN DONDE LLAMO EL @LOGIN EN MI CONTROLADOR
PONGO OTRO NOMBRE, NO PASA NADA. Simplemente como si no llegara a esa funcion de mi controlador funcion, así que no se que esté pasando .**

Realmente me tiene mal , porque es algo básico pero no se, ahora quizás algo se me está pasando.

Estoy usando Lando + Docker

& está es mi configuración

```html
name: xxx
recipe: laravel
config:
  webroot: public
  php: 7.4
  via: nginx
  database: 'mysql:8.0'
proxy:
  appserver_nginx:
//
services:
  node:
    type: 'node:14'
tooling:
  npm:
    service: node
    cmd: npm
```

Comment: Cerraste esa etiqueta `<form>`cierto? Y esto `return $request;` que se supone que haga? Típicamente después de una solicitud post se redirige a utra ruta

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  he trabajado con  varios proyectos jajaja pero realmente no se que pase aquí :( el return del request tenía más cosas de hecho el formulario es más grande. solo quite el código y quiero que llegue del otro lado. pero no lo hace :/.   Realmente estoy ._.

Comment: Mira en la pestaña network del navegador si cuando presionas el botón Entrar se envía la solicitud

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ como te comento la pagina se actualiza

Comment: Es normal que se actualice salvo que tu petición se haga mediante AJAX, se te pide que verifiques la pestaña de network por ejemplo para ver que código obtienes como respuesta de la petición, por otro lado si cambias ese return por un dd() del $request no aparece nada?

Comment: @BetaM He hecho de todo, Quizás no se si tenga que ver con Lando la configuración porque inclusive como digo si en mi webRoutes pongo otro nombre a mi funcion, aunque no exista. no pasa nada .. así que no se que este pasando

Comment: ¿La URL a la que eccedes se ve así https://tu-dominio/iniciar o así https://tu-dominio/public/iniciar?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ    http://localhost:52949/iniciar

Comment: Como comente, ando usando Lando Esas rutas me las genera. luego me genera más rutas.  . .  todo  rarisimo ..

Answer (score 0):

prueba de esta forma tu codigo:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('entrar') }}">
        {{ method_field('post') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
    
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"> ENTRAR </button>
    
        <button type="reset">Borrar</button>
    
    
    </form>
```

y en tu controlador prueba de esta forma:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request->all());
        
        return $request;
    }
```

Comment: Convendría que acompañes tu código con una breve explicación

Comment: No eso no sirve :( es que ...  como lo he dicho en mi funcion que apunta mi controlador jamás pasa por ahí. & aunque ponga otro nombre no me arroja Error. :/

Comment: y si pruebas cambiando la ruta de esta forma....    Route::post('/entrar', 'LoginAccountController@login')->name('entrar');